# Match all YouTube urls except user accounts and channels urls

Tags: regex

Could you please help me to find a regex that match all YouTube urls except user accounts and channels urls

I am using this regex:

```
https?:\/\/((www|m)\.)?(youtube\.com|youtu.be)\/((^channel\/|^user\/){0}(embed\/|(watch)?(\?|\/)?v(=|\/)?))(\S+)?
```

It works fine but youtube url with format of " https://youtu.be/abcdefgh " is not match

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
https?:\/\/((www|m)\.)?(youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?!user\/|channel\/)(embed\/|(watch)?[?\/]?v[=\/]?)?(\S*)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/J4tdCW/2). Note the `(embed\/|(watch)?[?\/]?v[=\/]?)?` part is now optional with the help of the `?` quantifier.

The `(?!user\/|channel\/)` part will disallow `user/` and `channel/`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the regex should ignore the channel and user accounts such as :

https://www.youtube.com/user/xxxxx
https://www.youtube.com/channel/xxxxx

Comment: @ZuhairAli Added that requirement to the solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help